# Good or Bad OOP?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

Assume there is an abstract class with a constructor that calls a protected abstract method that is yet to be implemented by the child class. Is this a good or bad idea? Why?

Comment: Yes. abstract classes were a bad idea.

Comment: Abstract classes aren't a bad idea - just the ability to call virtual methods from within a constructor.  The idea's bad for concrete classes, too - not just abstract ;)

Comment: @Reed, nope, abstract classes are a bad idea (albeit for other reasons). Typically delegation / aggregation is a better, less error-prone mechanism for code reuse than inheritance. Interface inheritance is fine (i.e. no implementation), but class inheritance was a terrible idea.

Comment: Interfaces are better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad idea.

You're basically creating inversion of control within a constructor.  The method in the base class that is being called gets called before the base class data is initialized (in most languages), which is dangerous, as well.  It can easily lead to indeterminate behavior.

Remember, in most languages, when you construct a class, all of the base class construction runs first.  So, if you have something like: `MyClass() : MyBaseClass() {}`, typically, `MyBaseClass`'s constructor runs in its entirety, **then** `MyClass`'s constructor executes.  However, by using a virtual method in the base class, you're calling an instance method in `MyClass` before it's fully initialized - which could be very dangerous.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea, because in most OOP languages, the child is initialized after the parent is initialized. If the abstract function is implemented in the child, then it may operate on data in the child under the incorrect assumption that it has already been initialized, which is not the case in parent construction.

Example:

```
 class Base {
     public:
         Base() { virtualInit(); }
         virtual ~Base() {}
     protected:
         virtual void virtualInit() {}
 };

 class Derived : public Base {
     public:
         Derived() : ptr_(new SomeObject) {}
         virtual ~Derived() {}
     protected:
         virtual void virtualInit() {
               // dereference ptr_
         }
     private:
         scoped_ptr<SomeObject> ptr_;
 };
```

In the example above, `Base::Base()` gets executed before `Derived::Derived()`, which is responsible for initializing `ptr_`. Hence, when `virtualInit()` is called from `Base::Base()` it dereferences an uninitialized pointer, leading to all sorts of trouble. This is why ctors and dtors should call only non-virtual functions (in C++), final functions (in Java), or the language-specific equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the reasoning of why you would want to do this, let alone qualify it. Sounds like your trying to inject some functionality into the object. Why wouldn't you just overload the constructor or create a property that can be set so that you can inject the functionality through composition or even create the constructor with a parameter which is the IOC object.

As another has already posted, it does depend on the context in which your trying to solve a particular problem. The natural fit would be to adhere to an interface, develop an abstract class, and overload the constructor in each implementation. Without further information I can only comment on what has been posted in your question.

This design you have can not be regarded good or bad. Simply from the fact that it may be the only way you can achieve what your trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not actually trying to solve a particular problem. Just asking for opinions for a possible design solution.

Comment: how are interfaces better? What if I needed a common class for all classes to inherit from? The common class itself should not be instantiated directly, but contains a number of methods and properties that descendant classes need? Wouldn't you need an abstract class so that you can benefit from inheritance?

Comment: Personal preference, I always go for composition over inheritance in my program designs. I find the solutions to be more robust. I would look at the problem using the CRC approach and work out the interactions more than the inheritance. An object has a responsibility and should be very good at it. It should also be able to be replaced by another of similar type. I would therefore look at the behaviours and design around these first. Not saying I wouldn't do inheritance, but its not something I think of from the onset, it usually happens down the line when I re-factor.

Answer (score 0):

It is only then a GOOD idea, IFF you can manage it to not shoot in your own foot. But anyway, OOP is always prone to bad designs; so if your language allows other paradigms than OOP, to use OOP in this case is definitely a BAD choice.

At least in C++,
the child class defines in which sequence all the initialisations are made; that are the initialisations of all member-variables and the constructors of all parent classes. This has to be considered!

Alternatively, you could give the constructor (as parameter) a pointer to a specific function (I would prefer static functions), instead of calling an abstract member-function. This could be a far more elegant and sane solution; and this is the usual solution in (probably all) non-OOP languages. (in java: A pointer to one function or a list of functions is the design pattern of an interface and vice versa.)